# Need solution for following scenario in Hibernate many to many mapping

Tags: spring, hibernate, many-to-many

Consider the tables where **posts** and **tags** exhibit a many-to-many relationship between each other.

The many-to-many relationship is implemented using a third table called post_tags which contains the details of posts and their associated tags.

```
Post Model

@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 250)
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    @Lob
    private String content;

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "posted_at")
    private Date postedAt = new Date();

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "last_updated_at")
    private Date lastUpdatedAt = new Date();


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
            })
    @JoinTable(name = "post_tags",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "post_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id") })
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();


    public Post() {

    }

    public Post(String title, String description, String content) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.content = content;
    }

    // Getters and Setters (Omitted for brevity)
}
```

---

```
TAG Model

@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @NaturalId
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
            },
            mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();

    public Tag() {

    }

    public Tag(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Getters and Setters (Omitted for brevity)
}
```

Problem is

I tried to use an existing tags. and insert happened only on posts & posts_tags table.

Initially i'm Get tag(s) with tagName(s). Once you have the Tag object, you can set it in the Post object and save it.

Like this

```
 Post post = new Post("Hibernate Many to Many Example with Spring Boot",
                "Learn how to map a many to many relationship using hibernate",
                "Entire Post content with Sample code");

        // Create two tags
        Tag tag1 = tagService.getTag("Spring Boot");


        // Add tag references in the post
        post.getTags().add(tag1);

        postRepository.save(post);
```

**If I do like that, entry is not available in post_tags table.**

Tag Repository and Tag Service:

```
@Repository
public interface TagRepository extends JpaRepository<Tag, Long> {

    @Query("select p from Tag p where p.name = :name")
    Tag findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}

@Override
public Tag findByName(String name) {
  return repository.findByName(name);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of tagService.getTag

Comment: Here I updated the tagService,getTag() for your reference

Comment: Still unable to find getTag method...